# Determining if a matrix is positive definite and symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Consider the following outputs from Matlab:

```
» R = chol(A)

  R = 1. 4142 0. 7071                                        
            0 1. 2247 

» A - R'*R

ans = 
 1.0e-15 * 
 -0.4441    0
       0    0.2220
```

I am trying to determine if the matrix $A$ is positive definite and symmetric.

A matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has a Cholesky factorisation $$A=R^TR$$ if and only if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, where $R$ is an upper triangular matrix with positive diagonal entries.

By the theorem above, if $A$ was positive definite I would expect $A-R^TR=0$, which is not the case in the output above. If given $A$ explicity, it would be much easier to determine if the matrx was positive definite and symmetric. Though, I do not see how to determine what is required by what is given.

Comment: 1.0e-15 seems a numerical zero. In any case for a 2x2 matrix I'm pretty sure that any such factorization can be performed analytically (for a symmetric real matrix). To determine if $A$ is positive, given that it's symmetric, simply compute the eigenvalues and check if they are positive.

Comment: @Icv How would you suggest that I compute the eigenvalues of $A$? The matrix is not given.

Comment: What do you mean is not given? If you compute chol(A), A is stored in memory.

Comment: @Icv I have not computed anything. Everything that was provided in the question has been given. We are to deduce what has been asked ONLY using the Matlab outputs that I have given. If the matrix $A$ was given, the problem would be very simple.

Comment: I see. My first comment still stands. That is a numerical zero. Unless you are told that the matrix A has entries of order 10e-15.

Comment: @Icv Agreed. Maybe we can use the theorem. The output suggests that $A$ has a valid Cholesky factorisation, then $A$ must be positive definite and symmetric (if and only if statement).

Answer (score 1):

OK. Well, the matrix $A$ is not a matrix of real numbers; it's a matrix of floats (or doubles). So the theorem, as stated, doesn't apply. Whether the examiners want to ignore that distinction, in which case it's reasonable to treat $10^{-15}$ as more-or-less zero, or carefully attend to that distinction, in which case I suppose the fact that $A - R'R$ is, strictly speaking, nonzero, you'd have to say that $A$ is not spd.

I guess I'd seek out a better quality of exam-writers. :(

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, 1.0e-15 = 0 for our purposes here. Since you have R, you can easily calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of A as follows:

```
[V,D] = eig(R'*R)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mention that this question is to be done by pen. It is a question I found in an old written exam paper.

Comment: Ah ok. The principle is still the same; just calculate $R^T R$, then find the zeros of the characteristic polynomial as usual. And to make life easier, use the exact values of R: $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}/2$, and $\sqrt{3/2}$.

Comment: Those are *not* the exact values in $R$; those are the real numbers that the values in the matlab matrix $R$ are good approximations to.

Comment: Fair enough, since it's impossible to exactly represent irrational numbers numerically. But given that $1.4142^2=1.99996164$, $1.2247^2=1.49989009$, and $0.7071^2=0.49999041$, you'll probably be ok rounding to the nearest 100,000th.